# Usage of passive form

Tags: grammar

I've got a question about this part - それらの音が、世界の中心にあることを思い知らされ. I cannot understand why it's used passive form verb（思い知らされる） and それらの音**が**. If I'm understanding correctly, the ones who "make you realize something are those sounds"
So, is it a mistake here, some sort of "author's stylistic" or I'm just misunderstanding something?

> いつもは車の音や街の音にかき消されてしまう、世界の囁き。それらの音が、世界の中心にあることを思い知らされ、だから、人の世界の不在を強く実感してしまうのだ
>
> "The world's whisper, which is always erased by the sounds of cars and
>   streets. Those sounds makes you realize, that you are in the center of
>   the world, that is why..."

Comment: あっ、ごめん、コメント消しちゃった～ww

Comment: まぁ、気にしないでください～
説明してくれてありがとうございます

Comment: 「思い知らされ、だから」seems a bit strange to me. Is that really the wording? Or does the sentence not stop at しまうのだ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (それらの音が、世界の中心にある)ことを思い知らされ(る)

それらの音 is the subject for 世界の中心にある. The subject for 思い知らされ(る) and 強く実感してしまう is 私/私たち(I/we/you).

Comment: そうだ、それらの音ってつまり、車の音や街の音ですか

Comment: はい～そうです～　You realize/are made acutely aware that these sounds/noises(=車・街の音≒喧騒) are in the center of the world... て感じかなと思います